# Headers configuration in Spring Security 6 for automated testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, http-headers, spring-test

I am using the following configuration code for an automated test using Spring Security:

```
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class SecurityConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)
                throws Exception {
            http.headers().xssProtection().and()
                    .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'");
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

Recently, I'm getting several warnings because these methods are marked as deprecated:

```
The method xssProtection() from the type HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity> has been deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
The method headers() from the type HttpSecurity has been deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
The method contentSecurityPolicy(String) from the type HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity> has been deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
The method and() from the type HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.XXssConfig has been deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal
```

Does anybody know how to make the same configuration using the new configurer/customizer API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like...

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
  http.headers(headers -> 
     headers.xssProtection(
        xss -> xss.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK)
     ).contentSecurityPolicy(
        cps -> cps.policyDirectives("script-src 'self' .....")
    ));
  return http.build();
}
```

ref: [documentation exploits headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/servlet/exploits/headers.html#servlet-headers-csp)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have JWT authentication too so i use this approach

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.XXssProtectionHeaderWriter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AdB2CConfiguration {

    @Value("${security.bypass.urls:#{null}}")
    private String[] bypassUrls;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000L)
                        .and()
                        .frameOptions().deny()
                        .xssProtection().headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK)
                        .and()
                        .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';"
                                + "font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';"
                                + "frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;"
                                + "object-src 'none';script-src 'self';"
                                + "script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';"
                                + "upgrade-insecure-requests")
                )
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(bypassUrls).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```